# what is the difference between boto3 `get_object()` & `download_file()`?

Tags: python, boto3

I was wondering what is the difference between boto3 `get_object()` & `download_file()`? I know the former is for getting an object and the latter is for downloading an object as a file. but is there any other difference? like in terms of one being faster? or preference?